# Python Cut/Copy paste file from folder to another folder

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure, file-structure

I have bunch of PDFs that are reports generated by system named 00002755, 00002758, 00002760 ...so on etc.

I already have Folders named exactly as above 00002755, 00002758, 00002760 ...so on etc.

What i want to achieve is cut the PDF file "00002755.pdf" and paste it inside Folder named "00002755"

My Folder at the moment looks like this:

1. Folder - 00002755
2. Folder - 00002758
3. Folder - 00002760
4. 00002755.pdf
5. 00002758.pdf
6. 00002760.pdf

The conclusion would be when I run the python script all the pdfs will go into their respective folders.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? To move a file in python you could use the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) module in a loop together with [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Comment: @SuperKeksmann, The problem was simply cut paste the 'Named' PDFs into 'Named' folder...the python OS module worked as answered by SCL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accomplished in different ways with different modules, here I'll use os only which should be fine and quite fast too (never benchmarked this with huge amounts of files/dirs, feel free to do so if you need it for your task)

```
import os


curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # Get current abspath based on your py file name

for i in [f.name for f in os.scandir(curr_dir) if f.is_dir()]:  # Iterate through the dirs
    for j in [f.name for f in os.scandir(curr_dir) if f.is_file()]:  # Iterate through the files
        if i == j.split(".pdf")[0]:  # If both match each other, move the file with os.rename
            os.rename(f"{curr_dir}\\{j}", f"{curr_dir}\\{i}\\{j}")
```

Comment: Thanks Mate ! This worked like charm. Saved me a lot of time on meaningless task of cut pasting into folder and the error that could have occurred if wrong file copied into wrong folder.